# Boolean algebra - cube - minimal disjunctive normal form

Tags: logic, computer-science, boolean-algebra

I have a test coming up and I would like to know how to solve these kinds of problems. This is the description:

```
Find MDNF (minimal disjunctive normal form) of the function F(A, B, C),
which is described by the cube. A full circle means logical 1, an empty
circle means logical 0.
```

[image: The problem]

How do I solve this in general?

Comment: First write out the truth table. Secondly, have you heard of [Karnaugh Map](http://http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map)? Also since you have $4$ options, and your truth table has only $2^3=8$ entries, you can just check them one by one, if you want.

Comment: Could you please provide some more guidance as to how to set up tha Karnaugh Map in this case?

Comment: Can you interpret the cube to get the truth table?

Comment: Consider the eight corners. And whether these points $(a,b,c)$ have value $0$ or $1$

Comment: OK, I created the truth table based upon the boolean cube. I have truth values for `010, 011, 100, 101`. Is that correct? What should be my next step?

Comment: 1) I find the instruction is rather cryptic (what is a "full circle", as it means what I think it means it doesn't look like a circle, is here a translation gremling working? ) 2) I think the truthtable you gave ( 010, 011, 100, 101) is not correct. Can you try to rephrase your question better, or with more detail (how is the cube constructed?, what does it mean?, probably if you try to explain the solution will show itself utomaticly.

Answer (score 1):

The cube diagram can be translated into a sum of [minterm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form#Minterms) expression:

```
(a and b and !c) or (!a and b and !c) or (a and !b and c) or (!a and !b and c)
```

This can be depicted as [Karnaugh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) map to visualize that the four 3-literal terms can be merged into two 2-literal terms:

```
             ab
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   0  | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
c     +---+---+---+---+
   1  | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```

The minimal sum of [minterms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form#Minterms):

```
(!b and c) or (b and !c)        [corresponds to mutiple-choice answer (d)]
```

The minimal product of [maxterms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form#Maxterms):

```
(b or c) and (!b or !c)
```